# quantstrat enable.rule not working

Tags: r, quantstrat

When I use `enable.rule` I cannot override the rule's internal `enabled=FALSE`.

**For example:**

```
## Stop Loss Rule
stratstocky <- add.rule(stratstocky,
                        name = "ruleSignal",
                        arguments = list(sigcol = "sdH", 
                                         sigval = TRUE,
                                         replace = FALSE,
                                         orderside = "long",
                                         ordertype = "stoptrailing",
                                         tmult = TRUE,
                                         threshold = quote(stopLossPercent),
                                         orderqty = "all",
                                         orderset = "ocolong"),
                        type = "chain",
                        parent = "getLong",
                        label = "StopTrailingLong",
                        enabled = FALSE
)
```

When I place this code before applyStrategy:

```
enable.rule(stratstocky, type="chain", "StopTrail", enable=TRUE)
```

The rule will not become enabled or active. The only way to activate the rule it to change it's internal enable to `TRUE`. I have tried exact spelling but it is not working for me.

This is not a big issue as I can just parameterize the rule's internal enable and control it this way but would prefer to use the existing code to run my system.

Any insight into `enable.rule` issues?

Answer (score 5):

Your example is not reproducible, but I can reproduce your problem with some assumptions.

It appears that you are mixing up `store=TRUE` and `store=FALSE`

Your `add.rule` call appears to assume `store=FALSE`, and then you pass your `stratstocky` object to `enable.rule`.

When `store=FALSE` , `enable.rule` will return the strategy object.  I believe that in your use case, you probably want:

`stratstocky <- enable.rule(stratstocky, type="chain", "StopTrail", enable=TRUE)`

to update your object with the now-enabled rule.

To create a reproducible example, try

`demo('macross',ask=FALSE)`

which will run the demo, and create some objects.  Like what I presume to be your example, the macross demo uses `store=FALSE`.

now:

`stratMACROSS <- enable.rule(stratMACROSS,type='exit',label='ruleSignal.rule',enable=FALSE)`

will disable the exit rule, and

`stratMACROSS <- enable.rule(stratMACROSS,type='exit',label='ruleSignal.rule')`

will enable it again.